# Get unread count with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem getting this query to work, so the basic idea is:

- I have messages table, I want to track whether user has read a message or not. Note: multiple users can receive same message, so simply adding column read to message is not an option
- Each message is in a thread (has a column thread_id)
- I have another table `user_read_message` which adds record whenever somebody reads a message (`user_id`, `message_id`, `read`)

I want to get number of unread messages for a user in a specific thread. I was trying something along these lines but I couldn't get it to work:

```
SELECT m.thread_id, urm.user_id, urm.read 
FROM sup_messages as m 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user_read_message as urm ON m.id = urm.message_id
WHERE m.thread_id = 76852 AND urm.user_id = 1337;
```

Which would if it worked selected all messages in thread_id 76852 then joined `user_read_message` where `user_id` is 1337 and messages which he hasn't read will simply have `null`. I would then somehow count where read is 0 or `NULL`.

ps. If there is better idea how to model this please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this.  Add your `WHERE` clause related to the user_read_message table into the `JOIN` to that table.  Since this is a `LEFT JOIN`, all of the fields returned from that table will be `NULL` if there is no match.  Add a field from that table to your `WHERE` clause that is always populated and then check to see if it is `NULL`.  That would mean there is no match.

```
SELECT m.thread_id, 1337 AS user_id, COUNT(*) unread_messages 
FROM  sup_messages as m 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN user_read_message as urm 
      ON m.id = urm.message_id
      AND urm.user_id = 1337
WHERE m.thread_id = 76852 AND urm.message_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This is the weirdest query I have ever seen, but it works! Could you elaborate and explain in more details? (Will accept as soon as I can :))

Comment: I added an explanation.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Yup it helps a bit, can I ask why is there 1337 AS user_id? It also works without it. Oh I get the idea, I didn't even know I can do more comparisons than 1 after ON statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sup_messages
WHERE sup_messages.thread_id = 76852 AND
      sup_messages.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT urm.message_id
                          FROM urm
                          WHERE urm.user_id = 1337 AND urm.read = 0)
```